# Find $a,b$ such that the equation $x^4+3x^3+6x^2+ax+b=0$ has at most 2 real roots. Solution using algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, roots, parametric

> Find $a,b$ such that the equation $x^4+3x^3+6x^2+ax+b=0$ has at most 2 real roots.

I tried doing it with calculus even though, it's at the algebra/polynomial chapter... but however I don't get much information using calculus since:

Let $f(x) = x^4+3x^3+6x^2+ax+b$. We get: $f'(x) = 4x^3+9x^2+12x+a$ and $f''(x)=12x^2+18x+12 >0 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$ There for $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ so it has $1$ root. Let's call that root $\alpha$ then we get $f'(x)<0\forall x\in(-\infty,\alpha)$ and $f'(x)>0\forall x\in(\alpha,\infty)$, then $f(x)$ is decresing from $\infty$ to $f(\alpha)$ and then increasing from $f(\alpha)$ to $\infty$. so we get $2$ roots only if $f(\alpha)<0$. Then $f$ has at most 2 real roots $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}.$

Do you have any idea how to solve this with algebra?

Comment: The statement seems to be true for *any* $a,b$, by your logic. Indeed, if $f'' > 0$ then $f'$ has atmost one real root and $f$ has atmost two real roots, regardless of the value of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It is indeed true $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. But how to solve this using algebra

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We show that $f$ has always at most two real roots regardless of the value of $a$ and $b$.

**Algebra**. If the real quartic $f$ has at least $3$ real roots then all its roots are real, say $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. Then 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=-3\quad\mbox{and}\quad x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4=6.$$
Hence 
$$0\leq x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^2-2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)\\=(-3)^2-2\cdot 6=-3.$$
Contradiction.

**Calculus**. If $f$ has at least $3$  distinct real roots then by the Mean Value theorem $f'$ has at least $2$ distinct real roots and $f''$ has at least $1$ real root. Now for all real $x$,
$$f''(x)=12x^2+18x+12=6(2x^2+3x+2)>0$$
because $\Delta=3^2-3\cdot 2\cdot2=-3<0$. Contradiction.

Comment: Here we go, you found the elegance I was too lazy looking for XD

Comment: Yeah, man. that's what i concluded too. But I wanted to use algebra to solve this.

Comment: @C.Cristi See my revised answer.

Comment: @RobertZ Great job. What if the sum of the squares was also positive, how would you approach it then?

Comment: @C.Cristi What do you mean? $0<x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=-3$ is still a contradiction!

Comment: @RobertZ Think of not this particular problem... just another problem with some of the coefficients changed the same question.. you get everything the same until you get the sum of the new equation squares also positive... What would you do then?

Comment: @C.Cristi In general you should  consider the discriminant of the quartic: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots

Answer (score 0):

As the terms with even exponents can never become negative, your only problem is the $x^3$. Just set $a=0$ and make $b$ really big...
This is just me thinking quick and dirty, there might be some elegant solution - did you try and plot the function?

Comment: This may better be left as a comment. You have had sufficient reputation already.

Comment: I posted simultaneously with the other (better) answer and saw no reason to delete mine. Besides I do not care about my "reputation" as long as its above 50 (or so?) and I can comment. Feel free to downvote.